# reindexing system table, sysschobjs

Tags: sql-server

I have [strong suspicion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035780/system-table-weirdness) that I need to reindex/reorganize system table, `sys.sysschobjs`. How could I do that?

Comment: The problem described in linked question. In short: there is sql (generated) that is super slow and execution plan shows that it's because sys.sysschobjs clustered index.

Comment: Did you try just doing a rebuild with online = true?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg `ALTER INDEX clst ON sys.sysschobjs
REBUILD with (online=on);` outputs "Index cannot be created on object 'sys.sysschobjs' because the object is not a user table or view."

Comment: Looking at your link, the actual vs estimated rows is quite different.  Can you update the statistics on that table?  Can you add a where clause to it to reduce unneeded records?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg sp_updatestats nor UPDATE STATISTICS sys.sysschobjs didn't improve things, prohibitive where at the end (where 1=2) works fast:) I'll try to localize problem with minimum sql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is an expensive query, not an index that needs to be rebuilt. What would rebuilding accomplish? It might defragment the index or remove page empty space. All of these problems are likely to not impact performance in a way that you describe (51min query). Even if these problems exited in the most severe way I can imagine you will not get more than a small integer factor in performance improvement. This cannot solve your problem.

The query plan screenshot shows that the index scan is being performed 300k times. This is a red flag pointing to a query that has problems.

Optimize the query. (Can't help with that because the query plan is not available.)

Comment: I'd love to optimize it, but it is auto-generated from almighty visual studio entity framework model. Lesson here is not to use that.

Comment: I'd rather say know its limitations. It query capabilities are a poor shadow of what LINQ to SQL was which is deprecated. Anyway, just making sure this came across: I understand you can't change the query but reindexing is not helping. Do something else :)